# Group array by array name

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Something
            [other_id] => 2
            [other_name] => One
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Something
            [other_id] => 3
            [other_name] => Two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Something
            [other_id] => 3
            [other_name] => Three
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Something
            [other_id] => 2
            [other_name] => Four
        )

)
```

Now I need the array to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Something
            [0] => Array
                (
              [other_id] => 2
                  [other_name] => One
            )       
            [1] => Array
                (
              [other_id] => 3
                  [other_name] => Two
            )       
            [2] => Array
                (
              [other_id] => 4
                  [other_name] => Three
            )       
        )
)
```

I tried different ways but no result. I hope someone can help me a little bit with that.

Comment: Show us some efforts.

Comment: Some questions: (1) Are all the `id` always the same? (2) Would you consider using the `id` as key in the array? That would simplfy the code substantially.

Comment: No, id change. basically i need similar like that: http://jsfiddle.net/LkjL2584/

Comment: I take it then you don't use the keys for anything in particular, so it is fine for me to set them to whatever I want.

Comment: Wait... This doesn't make sense to me. In the input, you have the `other_id, other_name` combos `2, One`, `3, Two`, `3, Three` and `2, Four`. In the output you have `2, One`,  `3, Two` and `4, Three`. What are the rules here?

Comment: In showing table i thinked doing that way: http://jsfiddle.net/LkjL2584/1/

Comment: You still make no sense. The link does not answer my question. If you want help, you need to explain what it is you want. Edit your original question and explain how the output is supposed to be related to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you want, but this might do it:

```
//Somewhere to store the result.
$output = array();

//Loop through the input array.
foreach($input as $element) {

    $id = $element['id'];
    $other_id = $element['other_id'];

    if(!isset($output[$id])) {
        //ID is not already in the output array, so add it.
        $output[$id] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $element['name'],
        );
    }

    if(!isset($output[$id][$other_id])) {
        //Other_ID is not already in the output array, so add it.
        $output[$id][$other_id] = array(
            'other_id' => $other_id,
            'other_name' => $element['other_name'],
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not proper looping `for($element in $input)`

Comment: Okei, i tried that and it doesnt worked for me correctly because first other_id and other_name it doesnt group. Here is pastebin url: http://pastebin.com/ptnaspHi